# Is there a ketivat ot for tefillin or mezuzot?

Tags: safrus

I've heard and attended a few *ketivat ot* ceremonies for the writing of a Torah. I've never heard of a similar ceremony for tefillin or mezuzot. I assume that it may be that these items have far fewer letters? Nonetheless, there certainly are enough to write to have a few people assist in this. Is there such a thing as *ketivat ot* for these items? If not, how come?

Comment: It's not a big deal to finish a Mezuzah. People can write multiple Mezuzot in a day. No one's having a party about it. If you want to write a letter in one a Sofer who writes them could easily arrange for you to write the last letter in one

Comment: Perhaps the answer lies in the fact that Tefillin has to be written Kesidran (the Parshiyos are written in the order which it exists in the Torah) and multiple writers may not be able to accomplish this aspect.

Comment: In addition the size of the letters is smaller, which increases the danger of badly formed letters invalidating the work

Answer (score 4):

There is a distinct Mitzvah to write a Sefer Torah (specifically, [mitzvah number 613](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.613?lang=bi)). This can be accomplished by filling in a letter (as the [Rambam in Mishneh Torah, Tefillin, Mezuzah and the Torah Scroll 7:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Tefillin%2C_Mezuzah_and_the_Torah_Scroll.7.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes explicitly that even writing one lette fulfils the requirement). Since most people aren't writing their own Sifrei Torah, there are these 'events' that allow people to join in with minimal monetary contribution. There is no Mitzvah to write Tefillin or Mezuzah, therefore there are no 'events' to do so.